# Why is .then() never executed in this Node JS example, even though Promise is resolved?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, es6-promise

I am new to node and following Ryan Lewis' excellent course on advanced use of the AWS Javascript SDK. The code I wrote is according to the instructions and runs fine, it even connects to AWS and creates a security group as expected. After that it is expected to resolve the returned promise and continue by creating a key-pair and finally the instance. If there were an error, it is expected to be caught.

However, the code in the resolve (or reject) functions passed into the promise using the `.then()` and `.catch()` statements near the end is never executed, which is not expected.

I tried:

- restructuring the code a bit
- adding some logging
- adding a `setInterval()` at the end to prevent node from exiting

Here is my code:

```js
// Imports
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const proxy = require('proxy-agent')
const helpers = require('./helpers')

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'eu-central-1'
})

console.log(AWS.config)

// Declare local variables
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2()
const sgName = 'hamster_sg'
const keyName = 'hamster_key'

// Create functions
function createSecurityGroup(sgName) {
  const params = {
    Description: sgName,
    GroupName: sgName
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ec2.createSecurityGroup(params, (err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        const params = {
          GroupId: data.GroupId,
          IpPermissions: [
            {
              IpProtocol: 'tcp',
              FromPort: 22,
              ToPort: 22,
              IpRanges: [
                {
                  CidrIp: '0.0.0.0/0'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              IpProtocol: 'tcp',
              FromPort: 3000,
              ToPort: 3000,
              IpRanges: [
                {
                  CidrIp: '0.0.0.0/0'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
        ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(params, err => {
          console.log('Creating Security Group.')
          if (!err) {
            console.log('Calling Resolve.')
            resolve
          } else {
            reject(err)
          }
        })
      } else {
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  })
}

function createKeyPair(keyName) {
  const params = {
    KeyName: keyName
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ec2.createKeyPair(params, (err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        resolve(data)
      } else {
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  })
}

function createInstance(sgName, keyName) {
  const params = {
    ImageId: 'ami-026d3b3672c6e7b66',
    InstanceType: 't2.micro',
    KeyName: keyName,
    MaxCount: 1,
    MinCount: 1,
    SecurityGroups: [sgName],
    UserData:
      'IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKY3VybCAtLXNpbGVudCAtLWxvY2F0aW9uIGh0dHBzOi8vcnBtLm5vZGVzb3VyY2UuY29tL3NldHVwXzgueCB8IHN1ZG8gYmFzaCAtCnN1ZG8geXVtIGluc3RhbGwgLXkgbm9kZWpzCnN1ZG8geXVtIGluc3RhbGwgLXkgZ2l0CmdpdCBjbG9uZSBodHRwczovL2dpdGh1Yi5jb20vdGl0dXNuL2hhbXN0ZXJjb3Vyc2UuZ2l0CmNkIGhiZmwKbnBtIGkKbnBtIHJ1biBzdGFydAo='
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ec2.runInstances(params, (err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        resolve(data)
      } else {
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  })
}

// Do all the things together
createSecurityGroup(sgName)
  .then(
    () => {
      console.log('SecurityGroup Created.')
      return createKeyPair(keyName)
    },
    err => {
      console.error('Failed to create instance with:', err)
    }
  )
  .then(helpers.persistKeyPair)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Keypair Created.')
    return createInstance(sgName, keyName)
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Created instance with:', data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to create instance with:', err)
  })

setInterval(function() {
  return console.log("I'm still running!")
}, 1000)
```

And here is the output:

```
Creating Security Group.
Calling Resolve.
I'm still running!
I'm still running!
I'm still running!
I'm still running!
I'm still running!
```

Node version is 10.16.0

When I set a breakpoint in IntelliJ on the line that prints "Calling Resolve." then I see the following:

[image: Variables pane in IntelliJ]

And this is the point where I am a bit lost. I cannot see if the `resolve` function is properly set. Is there any way to do that? But more importantly: what am I missing? It really doesn't seem like I am doing anything special (except maybe leaving out all the semicolons, which eslint and prettier made me do). So the question is simply: why are all the `then()` calls near the end of the code never executed, even though I am calling `resolve` nicely? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: uhm. `resolve;` doesn't call resolve, it just does nothing. Your code also seems to be missing a lot of semicolons.

Comment: I believe @KevinB is trying to advise you to change `resolve` to `resolve()`  (Nevermind the semicolon remark - they aren't necessary, it mostly a style thing.)

Comment: Kevin is right, but to make it even clearer, `resolve` is a variable containing a function, you need to call the funcion so you need the parenthesis: `resolve()`

Comment: eh, semicolons is far more than a style thing, without them, certain code structures  you wouldn't think twice about will throw an error.

Comment: Point taken, I was also wondering about that. I just wanted to try what happens when I use Prettier and Eslint on standard settings after installing (but not actually using) the airbnb styles. And did not really expect them to remove all semis...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `resolve` to `resolve()` in this:

```
    ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(params, err => {
      console.log('Creating Security Group.')
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Calling Resolve.')
        resolve
      } else {
        reject(err)
      }
```

so it becomes:

```
    ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(params, err => {
      console.log('Creating Security Group.')
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Calling Resolve.')
        resolve()     // <===== change here
      } else {
        reject(err)
      }
```

You have to actually call the function.  Just putting `resolve` in your code does nothing without parens after it.

---

FYI, it is generally considered a lot cleaner coding style to "promisify" your functions outside (creating separate functions/methods that return a promise), separately from their use so then your main coding logic and control flow shows only promise operations, not a mix of inline promises and callbacks.

Also, for functions that follow the node.js asynchronous calling convention of a callback with arguments `(err, data)` (which is only some of the async functions you're using), you can use [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to create promisified versions of your functions/methods without hand coding each one.

Comment: This is a great answer! And such a silly noob mistake to make... I know comments are not meant to say thank you, but I believe in positive feedback. Your answer is so good, because you also took the time to explain how to improve the code. I'll accept it after fixing the issue and trying your suggestion to use util.promisify().